# SSRS color formatting based on parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, iif

I have an SSRS report with a table that contains all months of the year (jan-dec) with corresponding data.

I have the following background color expression :

```
=IIF(VAL(Fields!YearMonth.Value) MOD 2 = 1,"Blue","White")
```

This will make january blue, february white, march blue, april white etcetera.  This works great.

Now, I have a parameter called Prognosis that can be either 0 or 1. When the parameter is set to 1, the report (table) returns prognosis data for the next months of the current year (november and december in this case since it is october)

If the data in the table is a prognosis (so Prognosis = 1), then the background color should be the color Orange. It should just be orange, so no need for orange white orange white etc.

Could someone help me with this expression statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following updated expression

```
=IIF( VAL(Fields!Prognosis.Value)=1,"Orange", IIF( VAL(Fields!YearMonth.Value) MOD 2 = 1,"Blue","White"))
```

The above expression will make all rows as orange background in case prognosis =1

Comment: Been struggling for hours to get it working. Works just like i want it to, thanks so much!